# How do I create a custom implementation for a specific type?

Tags: rust, traits

I have this code:

```
pub struct Tuple2<T>(pub T, pub T);

// default realization
impl<T: Mul<Output = T>> Mul<Tuple2<T>> for Tuple2<T>
{
    type Output = Tuple2<T>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Tuple2<T>) -> Tuple2<T> 
    {
        Tuple2(self.0 * rhs.0, self.1 * rhs.1)
    }
}
```

Now I want to override the method for `Tuple2<f32>`:

```
// specific realization for f32
impl Mul<Tuple2<f32>> for Tuple2<f32>
{
    type Output = Tuple2<f32>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Tuple2<f32>) -> Tuple2<f32> 
    {
        // custom code
        Tuple2(self.0 * rhs.0, self.1 * rhs.1)
    }
}
```

Error:
    conflicting implementations for trait `core::ops::Mul` [E0119]

Comment: I assume this is an artifact of how you are asking the question, but your `f32` case isn't different from your `T` case... is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this, since Rust doesn't currently have impl specialization - there can only be one implementation of any trait (and set of input parameters) for any type, any conflicting implementations yield compiler errors.